# Graphical user interface Tutorial in C

Tags: c, user-interface

I have a project in C language and the teacher ordered to make a Gui of project.
I can only use C or C++ for the GUI part.

Can anyone please suggest me Some easy open source Graphics Library Tutorial because this will be my first ever GUI.

thanks

Comment: Your teacher told you to write a GUI without any kind of direction? That's very odd. GUIs especially in C and C++ are quite complicated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The two most usual choices are [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/), which has documentation links [here](http://www.gtk.org/docs/), and is mostly used with C; or [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) which has documentation [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/latest) and is more used with C++.

I posted these two as you do not specify an operating system and these two are pretty cross-platform.

Comment: I changed GTK to GTK+ since that is more proper. Also, note that while GTK+ is a C API, there are wrappers for *many* programming languages.

Answer (score 11):

My favourite UI tutorials all come from zetcode.com:

- [wxWidgets](http://zetcode.com/gui/wxwidgets/) (C++, cross platform)
- [Win32api GUI](http://zetcode.com/gui/winapi/) (C, Windows)
- [GTK+](http://zetcode.com/gui/gtk2/) (C, cross platform)
- [Qt4 Tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/qt4/) (C++, cross platform)

These are tutorials I'd consider to be "starting tutorials". The example tutorial gets you up and going, but doesn't show you anything too advanced or give much explanation. Still, often, I find the big problem is "how do I start?" and these have always proved useful to me.

Answer (score 3):

You can also have a look at [FLTK](http://fltk.org/) (C++ and not plain C though)

> FLTK (pronounced "fulltick") is a cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit for UNIX®/Linux® (X11), Microsoft® Windows®, and MacOS® X. FLTK provides modern GUI functionality without the bloat and supports 3D graphics via OpenGL® and its built-in GLUT emulation.
>
> FLTK is designed to be small and modular enough to be statically linked, but works fine as a shared library. FLTK also includes an excellent UI builder called FLUID that can be used to create applications in minutes.

Here are some quickstart [screencasts](http://seriss.com/people/erco/fltk-videos/)

[Happy New Year!]